# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk installation commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying my API on elastic beanstalk. Everytime an instance is launched,  I need a specific folder "temp_storage" to have write access as this is where I store my images while resizing them before uploading to S3 bucket. I also need to install a few composer programs.

My setup is

```
fd-api/
     composer.json (These need to be installed)
     temp_storage/ (This folder needs write access)
     .ebextensions/
          temp-folders.config
```

**temp-folders.config**

```
container_commands:
  chown_folder:
    command: "chown -R webapp /var/www/html/fd-api/temp_storage"
  chmod_folder:
    command: "chmod 777 /var/www/html/fd-api/temp_storage"
```

This is my understanding of how it should work but when I attempt to run this I get the errors:

> Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-03f5ed1eb55f52d17'. Aborting the operation.
>
> Failed to deploy application.
>
> During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

I don't know where to begin debugging this? My understanding from reading is that composer files will automatically run every time an elastic beanstalk instance is generated and any commands in the .ebextension/something.config files will be run.

Not really sure what user webapp is? assuming it's the default user for an elastic beanstalk instance?

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: /var/log/eb-activity.log is log file on your instance where you can have a look at logs.

Comment: My guess is that the `temp_storage` folder doesn't exist when your commands are being run. ElasticBeanstalk first extracts all the files to a staging location, and then moves them into place after all of the deployment hooks (such as `container_commands`) have been executed. As @Zohaib said, `/var/log/eb-activity.log` should tell you exactly what's going on. Also, `webapp` is the user that will run your application.

Comment: @Brian Okay so do you think I should have the commands actually create the directory and then set the permissions to the newly created folder?

Comment: That depends on what your platform is going to do during the deployment. If it behaves like the Ruby platform, it might be deploying to something like `/var/www/html/staging` and then renaming it to `/var/www/html/fd-api` after all the hooks have been run. If that's the case, you'd want to create/chown/chmod the folder in the staging location. Can you post the relevant lines from `/var/log/eb-activity.log` and tell us what EB platform you're using?

Comment: It's all custom code so it's just plopping it into an elastic beanstalk instance with all the generic settings. I tried adding a mkdir command into the folder and that works but some reason when i run the chmod commands they dont work. I don't really know how to find relevant files in eb-activity.log since it's so long and don't really know how to go through it easily on a terminal @brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was that the commands in the .ebextensions file are run in lexicographical order. By adding 001, 002, 003, ... before the command names like so:

```
container_commands:
  001create_folder_nonsudo:
    command: "mkdir temp_storage"
  002chown_folder:
    command: "chown webapp temp_storage"
  003chmod_folder:
    command: "chmod 777 temp_storage"
```

ended up solving my problem

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that! I always prefix my commands with numbers out of habit, but forgot how important it is.

Comment: @Brian all good, thank you very much for the help! I appreciate it.